# Catching IP from users trying to acces nonexisting urls in a MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, model-view-controller

I have a C# MVC application in production. At a daily basis the application is called like:

> /wp/wp-admin/
>
> /api
>
> /Account/Login

Without doubt those calls are attempt to attack the application.
Because those urls are not implemented an exception is thrown :
*System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): The controller for path '/api/xmlrpc' was not found or does not implement IController.*

The exception is catched in Global.asax.cs:

```
 protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
     .....
 }
```

My problem is that I don't have access to the request in the Global.asax.cs file, so I can't get the IP-address.

What is the best practice to catch information about users trying to scan your MVC application for vulnerabilities?

Comment: If some one is attempting to attack your application, it's also highly likely they would be spoofing their IP address, which is trivially easy to do. Having an IP is no magic bullet anyways. Usually these things are done by users in places like Russia and China, where there is no jurisdiction you could take advantage of to actually penalize them in any way. There's no harm in generating 404s, and that's the worst they're going to do by attempting to hit nonexistent URLs.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should have access to the request object in `Application_Error` event at Global.asax.cs where a few particular events have not.

```
 protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
    Server.ClearError();
    string ip = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Might not be the "best" practice but if you add in [ELMAH](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Elmah.MVC/), it will log the errors and should include the IP address of the incoming request.  I haven't used it to discern attackers, but in my apps that have used ELMAH, it does record the IP address when the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all.
I used Ibubi's suggestion combined with the advice from Chris Patt.

I ended up with this solution:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    // GET: Error
    public ActionResult NotFound()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Session["User"] == null)
        {
            Log(HttpContext.Request.UserHostAddress);
            return View(); // an empty page
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("NotFound","Home" ); // Information page for users
        }
    }
}
```

and in Glocal.asax.cs as suggested by Ibubi:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
   protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
       Server.ClearError();
       string ip = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
       Log(ip);
   }
}
```